# Highlight maximum entry in data table of excel bar chart

Tags: excel, vba, bar-chart, excel-2016

I have an excel bar chart showing data table with it as shown in image below.

[image: Excel bar chart with data table]

I like to highlight maximum entry in bold font for each column. for example, as we can do in separate data table as shown in image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Import code to module:

1. Open Excel
2. Press ALT +F11
3. Insert
4. Module
5. Paste the below Code.

**Notes:**

- If "Option Explicit" already exist avoid paste.
- The table must imported in Sheet1 starting from A1.

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Sub Test()

  Dim Lastrow As Long, LastColumn As Long, i As Long, MaxValue As Long

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

      Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

      For i = 2 To LastColumn
          MaxValue = Application.Max(.Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(Lastrow, i)))
              For j = 2 To Lastrow
                  If .Cells(j, i).Value = MaxValue Then
                      .Cells(j, i).Font.Bold = True
                      Exit For
                  End If
              Next j

      Next i

  End With

  End Sub
  ```

Output:
[image]

Comment: can you please tell where to put this code? sorry, I am layman in excel ...

Comment: @AsifKhan check the new answer.

Comment: But I like these entries bold in charts data table. (The data table attached with bar chart as shown in first image of this question).

Comment: ok, i thought that your trying to format a table like the image below graph.No idea how to format graph's table.